# What is the complement of $A = \{1,3,5\}$ in $S = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Roll a 6 sided die once. Let $S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ be the sample space of all possible things that could happen. Let the event $A=\{1,3,5\}$ and the event $B=\{1,4\}$.

What is the complement of $A$?

Comment: You may benefit from reading the definition of "complement", and studying the examples of it that your text undoubtedly provides directly after that.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** $\overline{A} = S - A$. Which events in the sample space are not in $A$?

Comment: "-" only applies to numbers, not sets.

Comment: @zettasuro: That's fairly common notation, actually. Still, it is a bit ambiguous, so $S\smallsetminus A$ is preferable.

Answer (score 3):

What is the set of members of $S= \{ 1,2,3,4,5,6 \}$ which do not also belong to $A=\{ 1,3,5 \}$?  You have that $1$ belongs to both $A$ and $S$, $3$ belongs to both $A$ and $S$, and $5$ belongs to both $A$ and $S$.  What members of $S$ do not match like this?

Comment: Please, could you use TeX? It makes everything so much more readable.